# How get the default language of a translatable node bundle?

Tags: nodes, i18n-l10n

I'm on D10. I have a translatable content type, e.g. node, *article* bundle.

How can I get programmatically its default language code, defined in the settings form?

I've tried

```
  $entity_type_manager = \Drupal::entityTypeManager();
  $node_type_definition = $entity_type_manager->getStorage('node_type')->load('article');
```

But that contains always the site default language, no matter what I set in the form.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snippet code: to get the default langcode defined in the settings form: (Drupal 9/10)

```
use Drupal\language\Entity\ContentLanguageSettings;

// Get the default langcode that selected in the entity's setting form
$lang_config = ContentLanguageSettings::loadByEntityTypeBundle('node', 'article');
$selected_langcode = $lang_config->getDefaultLangcode();
```

**Note:** node denotes entity_type, article denotes bundle/node type